# Select commands from bash history

Tags: bash, history

Pressing the up button is tedious and I might miss the command I was looking for. So when typing `history` at the terminal gives me all the commands I have entered before, indexed to a number. Is there any way I could just call the number associated with the command?

Comment: any more interactive option by now? these are so error prone

Answer (score 54):

The bash history can do many helpful things, and the search with `Strg-r` that Terry Wang mentioned is an important one among them. But it is also possible to do exactly what you asked for.

You can re-do the previous command with `!!`. With this, you can also edit the previous command. If for example you forgot to get root privileges for a command

```
apt-get install a-long-list-of-packages
```

you don't have to retype all of that again. Instead just call

```
sudo !!
```

If you want to re-execute the command at a specific position from your history, you can also use `!`, for example

```
!3
```

to re-execute the command at position 3. Be aware that this counts from the top. So if you're storing 500 commands in your history, `!1` would be "500 commands ago". You can also use negative numbers. For example

```
!-2
```

would re-execute the second last command.

You can also re-execute the last command that started with a string like

```
!apt-
```

which would re-do the last line that started with "apt-". If you want the last command where the string appeared anywhere in the line, you can use something like

```
!?pt-ge
```

There are more interesting things the bash history can do. Just to give an impression of the wide range of possibilities, you can specifically access a parameter of a command from history. So

```
!-5:3:p
```

would print the third parameter to the fifth from last command.

EDIT: Regarding Rudie's comment below, with the standard settings this bash history expansions are indeed executed directly. It's probably best described like this: A call like `!-3` is *replaced* by the shell with the third last command from your history and *then* your input (with the replacement) executed. So if you type `!-3` and press `ENTER` and your third last command was `ls ~`, it's in effect the same as if you typed `ls ~` again and pressed `ENTER` "on your own".

If you don't want that, you can set the shell option `histverify`. For setting and unsetting shell options, you might want to read up on the `shopt` command. With `histverify` set, a call like `!-3` only writes the replacement from your history to your command line, but doesn't execute it directly. You have, so to speek, press the crucial `ENTER` yourself - or refrain from it, if you choose to.

Comment: So `!` is pretty damn dangerous... I'd want to know what `!-4` did exactly before running it. Or does it show you first? Cool summary!

Comment: @Rudie That's a good point, I updated my answer. The history features are mostly meant to speed up your work and save you keystrokes. So a standard "Do you really, really mean that?" would at least partially defeat that purpose. And even though you could, normally you won't call a "far back" command like `!-238`. It shouldn't be too hard to remember your second last, third last, maybe fith last command ;) As often with Linux (and, actually, with computing in general), it's expected that you know what you're doing. And if you really want the additional safety net, it's one `shopt` away ;)

Comment: I am getting `bash: !20471: command not found` when I do `!20471` when `20471` was the index of my last command...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine That's probably not a problem with the history. My guess would be that the command you've entered previously and now try to repeat isn't available anymore for some reason. Also, a history of more than 20.000 commands is _very_ large. The default is, if I'm not mistaken, 1.000 commands. Maybe you're running into some kind of limit there.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, there is. If, for example, you want to execute the command that has number 1234 next to it, do:

`!1234`

Other useful stuff:

- If you want to run the last command you ran, do:

  ```
  !!
  ```
- If you want to run the last `ls` command you ran, do:

  ```
  !ls
  ```
- If you just ran `ls /some/long/path`, and you want to `cd` to it, do:

  ```
  cd !$
  ```

For more information:

- [How To Use Bash History to Improve Your Command-Line Productivity](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/)

Comment: Why is this not the Top Answer?

Answer (score 8):

Using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, you will be able to use keywords to search your Bash history.

A quick bash key binding reference can be found here: http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html

Answer (score 7):

If you've found the history number of a command and you want to execute it again, type `!` followed by the number, e.g. `!1234` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is part of [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction); you can tack [modifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifiers) onto it.

If you want to edit the command before running it, `fc 1234` invokes an external editor.

But [as Terry Wang already mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342886/select-commands-from-bash-history/342887#342887) there are usually faster ways of locating a command in the history than determining its history number, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to invoke incremental search (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you've found the command you want to execute), or `fc PREFIX` to execute the previous command beginning with `PREFIX`.

Answer (score 3):

The `history` command will show all commands and their associated numbers. If you want to just do a quick check before executing command line # 135 you can type:

```
echo !135
```

This will show you what is going to be executed.